# FileHelpers on .NET 3.5 fails to compile

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, filehelpers

I'm trying to use **FileHelpers** library in my VS 2012 project targeting **.NET Framework v3.5**.
I installed it from NuGet without any warning/error. But when I try to compile my project I get those errors on many FileHelpers classes related to the Framework version:

```
The referenced assembly "FileHelpers, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was compiled on framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5"
```

Can't I use FileHelpers on a project targeting .NET Framework v3.5?

From [filehelpers.net](http://www.filehelpers.net/):

> Wide framework support: You can use the library in .NET 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.6 and Mono!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an in progress issue opened. You can see it [here](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/issues/168)

There is stated this temporary fix:

> However the version in Lib/net20 (in nuget package) references the .Net Framework v2.0:
>   It should be possible to use that version in your .Net 3.5 project.

Comment: No solution till now... from october 2015... Anyway linking manually the .Net 2.0 version of the library seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it seems they don´t think it´s a severe issue. But at least the 2.0 dll works :)